# Execute code after return

Tags: c#, thread-sleep, try-finally

On my web API, I want to delete a folder after my return statement.

```
public string Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    //Do cool stuff with request
    try
    {
        return "10.0.2.2:8080/myFolder/index.html";
    }
    finally
    {
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        Directory.Delete(myFolder, true);
    }
}
```

What I expected is that the device making the `POST` could get the return statement and load the `html` file. After a minute, we delete this file to free space on the server.

What happens is that the return statement is actually sent after the finally statement.

How can I run code after a return statement with delay, without delaying the return?

Comment: Things that you are trying to do is not possible, Process the operation from the calling method, after getting the response

Comment: I cannot create an async task with a `thread.sleep` inside it? Or you are telling me I need the device to make a `DELETE` call to the Web API?

Comment: Once you return it, the method is over. You can start a task with `Task.Delay(60000)`.

Comment: The finally-block will actually be executed before the method returns. Your current code would block for a minute, delete the folder and then return. https://dotnetfiddle.net/tReb0v

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll find an other way to do what I need.

Comment: Why not just return the file content? You are creating a tight coupling between this service that creates the file & the client that is using the file. You are creating a resource, handing a client a pointer to that resource, and then trying to guess when that client will be done with that resource so you can clean it up. That seems like a poor design choice.

Comment: @AshleyPillay Ask my boss why he did it like this, maybe to hide some data to the end user, even if it's still possible to read it. Anyway thanks for the advice!

Comment: Read up on `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that and it would be bad anyway, since you would keep resources (webserver threads for example) busy waiting.

Write another process (preferably a Windows service if you are on Windows) that checks the directory periodically and deletes all files of a certain age.

Comment: It is the actual way it's running. But people don't read documentation, and forget about this task went they set up a new Server.

Comment: @BeGreen Then make it more obvious (hint) or easier to access (settings). If it exists but people don't use it because they don't know (or forget) about it, it's a usability issue.

Comment: Well, "there is no way" is not actually true in my opinion. You may queue background work on the hosting environment for example. But since this requires advanced knowledge (i.e. exception handling and so on) I am not adding this as an additional answer. No offense (really! everyone starts somehow), but I think that someone who needs advice on how `try..finally` works should perhaps stick to refactoring instead. Anyway, [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710822/how-to-queue-background-tasks-in-asp-net-web-api) might be a good starting point for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

you can't execute code after return
in my opinion you can check files if the file created before 1m delete it

```
DirectoryInfo objDirectoryInfo = new 
                DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/files"));
foreach (FileInfo File in objDirectoryInfo.GetFiles) {
    if ((File.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1))) {
        File.Delete();
    }
}
```